# Install Xdebug; require PHP 7 while it installed

Tags: xdebug, centos7, php-7

When I type command `php -v` in **Linux CentOS 7** the output is:

```
PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: Feb 19 2018 03:52:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

But when in try to install Xdebug I got this error:

```
configure: error: not supported. Need a PHP version >= 7.0.0 and < 7.3.0 (found 5.6.33)
```

**What's the problem?**

## EDIT

I rebuild my PHP version and that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuild my php version and solved